# How to delete all non-matched data on Linux using awk or grep

Tags: linux, uniq

My data file is lines of network information, now I print all IDs. We need a generate ID and received ID, so if there is id: 4253, there should be another ID of 4253. How can I filter all data using awk or grep on Linux? I can use 'uniq' to filter all single ID, while I don't know if there is data generated and received, generated again but no received.[ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEZBG.png)

Comment: Is it possible to include a sample output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `grep -v`: `grep` gives you all the entries which match a criterion and `grep -v` gives you the entries which don't match it.